# For a set of data points approximating a closed curve, are there any interpolation methods that minimize SA:V?

Tags: curves, interpolation, plane-curves

I'm researching interpolation methods for a class. If I have the SA:V of the real shape (based on radius), I want to introduce that information into the curve fitting process. I think it would be easiest if starting from a curve with minimal SA:V based on the provided data points. Additionally: What background knowledge do I need?

Comment: What is SA:V ?…

Comment: SA:V refers to the surface area to volume ratio, as a function of the radius.